# I'm not able to understand logic of coin changing problem in o(sum) space complexity

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm facing difficulty in understanding O(sum) complexity solution of coin changing problem.
The problem statement is:
You are given a set of coins A. In how many ways can you make sum B assuming you have infinite amount of each coin in the set.

NOTE:

Coins in set A will be unique. Expected space complexity of this problem is O(B).

The solution is:

```
int count( int S[], int m, int n ) 
{ 
    int table[n+1]; 

    memset(table, 0, sizeof(table)); 

    table[0] = 1; 

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) 
        for(int j=S[i]; j<=n; j++) 
            table[j] += table[j-S[i]]; 

    return table[n]; 
}
```

can someone explain me this code.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's identify the parameters and variables used in the function:

Parameters:

- S contain the denomination of all m coins. i.e. Each element contain the value of each coin.
- m represents the number of coin denominations. Essentially, it's the length of array S.
- n represents the sum B to be achieved.

Variables:

- table: Element i in array *table* contains the number of ways sum i can be achieved with the given coins. `table[0] = 1` because there is a single way to achieve a sum of 0 (not using any coin).
- i loops through each coin.

Logic:
The number of ways to achieve a sum j = sum of the following:

- number of ways to achieve a sum of j - S[0]
- number of ways to achieve a sum of j - S[1]
  ...
- number of ways to achieve a sum of j - S[m-1] (S[m-1] is the value of the mth coin)

I did not completely decipher nor validate the rest of the code, but I hope this is a step in the right direction.

Added comments to code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count( int S[], int m, int n ) 
{ 
    int table[n+1]; 

    memset(table, 0, sizeof(table)); 

    table[0] = 1; 

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) // Loop through all of the coins
        for(int j=S[i]; j<=n; j++) // Achieve sum j between the value of S[i] and n.
            table[j] += table[j-S[i]]; // Add to the number of ways to achieve sum j the number of ways to achieve sum j - S[i]

    return table[n]; 
}

int main() {
    int S[] = {1, 2};
    int m = 2;
    int n = 3;
    int c = count(S, m, n);
    printf("%d\n", c);  
}
```

Notes:

- The code avoids repeats: 3 = 1+1+1, 1+2 (2 ways instead of 3 if 2+1 was considered.
- No dependence on the order of the coins in term of value.